# Unknown Payment Currency Code Error in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am working on a Prestashop project, where I am using AUD (Australian Dollar) as default currency, it works fine for AUD but when I try to convert it to USD or GBP then it gives me the error:

> Unknown Payment Currency Code

I am using Eway as the payment gateway, and I have not worked with Prestashop before.

Comment: have you added the currencies in "Localization > currencies"?

Comment: Are you testing with the eWAY Sandbox? It only supports one currency (AUD since you appear to have an AU one)

Comment: Can be closed under this official close reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.

Answer (score 1):

You need different eWAY Sandbox accounts for each currency. An eWay account is only linked to one currency.

[Here is a related post on Wordpress forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/v6018-unknown-payment-currencycode)